# good way to display db data the oop php way?

Tags: php, oop

Im working on making a blog in oop php. Now Im trying to display the post entries in my db. I manage to output data from the created field but nothing else. Basically I have four fields in the post table in my db. I have created, author, title and body. With this code below I only manage to display created. Anyone got any clued to how I should proceed?! Do I need to create a new blog object for every field?! That seems so weird if so. Thanks! BTW the code is from my index.php...

```
<?php
require_once('_settings.config.php');
            global $db;
            $blog = new Blog("My Blog");
            $posts = $blog->getPosts(); ?>

               <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
               <li>
               <?php echo "<div>"; ?>
                   <?php echo "<span class='footer'>Posted by: " . $post->author . "Created: " . $post->created . "</span>"; ?>
                  <?php echo "</div>"; ?>
               <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here as requested is my getPosts function. It returns the $posts array.

```
public function getPosts() {
        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM posts");
        $posts = array();
        while($post = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            array_push($posts, new BlogPost($post['id'], $post['created'], $post['author'], $post['title'], $post['body']));      
        }    
        return $posts;        
    }
```

Comment: If your `get_posts()` function would return an object it would work. Can you provide us the code for this function?

Comment: follow this it would help to you http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-world-oop-with-php-and-mysql--net-1918

Answer (score 0):

Does your post class have any additional functions? IMO, if it does, it makes sense to construct a new post object, so that way you could call `$post->do_something()` later on in the code. 
On the other hand, if your post class is just a container for the information that you pulled from the database, I would just create an instance variable `$posts` in your blog class that contains an array of hashes of all of the fields. Only real difference there is that you would have `$post['author']` instead of `$post->author` 
You could also define a function `display_all_posts()` or `display_posts(some_range)` for your blog object to make your code look nicer.

Comment: In my post BlogPost class I have the constructor and getters and setters for the fields in the database. Then in my blogclass I have the getPosts function that does the query and creates the BlogPost object which contains the fields in the database. Thats as far as I have come until now.